# Comparing two columns on sheet1 to two other columns on sheet2 and returning another column in sheet 2.

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to compare sheets1(a small list of names) First Name(Column A) and Last Name(Column B) to sheets2(a much larger list of names) First Name(column B) and Last Name(Column C). If I can find a match, I want to return Column F(user's email) from sheet2 to Column C in sheet1. 
I have no problem doing it with 1 column but I am having a hard time figuring out how to do it with two columns.

Comment: Need a little more information.  You're matching both names?  So First name and last name must be equal to return the email address?

Comment: Yes Im matching both the first and last name from sheet 1 to the first and last name in sheet2. But of course because one list is larger than the other, the names, if they match, will not be in the same column.

Comment: `=INDEX('Sheet2'!$C$1:$C$100,MATCH(1,INDEX(('Sheet2'!$A$1:$A$100=A1)*('Sheet2'!$B$1:$B$100=B1),),0))`

Comment: Not in the same column?  Do you mean not in the same row?  @ScottCraner beat me to it lol

Comment: Yes they may not be in the same row.

Comment: Any reason why the above formula would give me an error?

Comment: What error? and without test data provided by you it is hard to test.  the formula may not work.  The data may not be identical.  There may be unseen characters like spaces and carriage returns.  There are a lot of reasons that the formula may return an error.  Maybe the name of the sheet is wrong.  etc...

Comment: It is the basic "We found a problem with this formula". So it won't let me even attempt to use the formula.  It is highlighting the "$B$1" towards the end of the formula. My sheets are Sheet1 and Sheet2. Sheet1 ColumnA(First Name) ColumnB(Last Name). Sheet2 ColumnB(First Name) ColumnC(Last name). Return Column F if they match.

Comment: Use the formula from below.  The comments sometimes put unseen characters.  The one below should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$F$1:$F$100,MATCH(1,INDEX((Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100=A1)*(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$100=B1),),0))
```

[image]

---

Sheet 2 for reference

[image]

Comment: @user3809609 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Sorry it isn't returning to column c on sheet1, the user's email which is column F on sheet2.

Comment: @user3809609 did you consider studying the formula for 5 minutes?

Comment: I understand what this formula is doing. Does anywhere in column B on sheet 2 equal A1. and same for column B, and B1. I am guessing I need to add an if it is true then return ColumnF cell with correspondiing row. But I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: The first reference is the range in which the returned value can be found.  I changed this to column F on sheet 2.  See edit @user3809609